# How can I make Ubuntu successfully search for an environment variable for licenses?

Tags: linux, bash, networking, ubuntu, licensing

I have Ubuntu 10.04, 10.10, and 11.10 in virtual machines on oracles virtual box that I am testing products on. The licenses for the software to run is on my machine which is assigned a static IP.

SO what I have done for all the other Linux distributions I have done testing with is assign the .bashrc file a line in the end like this: export LICENCE=27065@192.168.1.45 causing it to look in the network for my machine to check out and check in its licenses. I have done the same with Ubuntu but cant get it to work at all! So far Ubuntu seems to be the only one with this problem.

SO i figured that maybe it was a connectivity issue. perhaps some behind the scenes security factor that i didn't know about. Well turns out I can ping my machine on the network just fine which makes me a little more lost.

Any info on this or even some more troubleshooting tips would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do the other machines (where this works) have SSH keyauth installed/working (does `~/.ssh` exist), and your Ubuntu machines do not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this a FlexLM license? It looks like it because of the port@hostname string.

- LICENCE looks wrong, these products usually use `LM_LICENSE_FILE` or `*$PRODUCTNAME*_LICENSE_FILE`, see eg. http://opendtect.org/lic/endusermanual/chap12.htm
- Check with telnet if this host/port is available: `telnet 192.168.1.45 27065`. It's possible that ping works but connecting to this specific port doesn't.
- Depending on how you start the shell in, `.bashrc` is not used, do you see it when you `echo` the variable? If not, stick it in `.bash_profile` instead
- Try setting `FLEXLM_DIAGNOSTICS=3` as described in the link above.

Comment: this is actually a rlm license. I actually didn't know about the way .profile worked; actually didn't even know of its existence. I put my code into the .profile instead of .bashrc and it worked like a charm. it looks like .bashrc works for the terminal after restart and the .profile works for both the terminal and the desktop. Thanks!!!